# Reducing disk space of sql database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I got a database that have 2TB of data, and i wanna reduce it to 500Go by dropping some rows and removing some useless columns, but i have other ideas of optimizations, and i need an answer of some questions before.

My database got one .mdf file, and 9 other .ndf file and each file has an initiale size of 100Go.

1. Should I reduce the initiale size of each .ndf file to 50Go? can this operation affect my data?
2. Dropping an index help to reduce space?

PS : My Database contains only one single table, that has one clustered index and two other non clustered indexes,

- I want to remove the two non clustered indexes
- Remove the insertdate column

If you have any other ideas of optimizations, it would be very helpful

Comment: If your database has only a single table - and you're not making use of any relational features, you might be better-off implementing your own flat-file store and indexing system.

Comment: You can't reduce the initial file size (unless that has changed in a recent version of SQL Server)

Comment: so you suggest that i create another database based on the first one ?

Comment: You might look at shrinking the database to recover storage due to fragmentation, after deletion of records.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu okay i'll at this point, can the action of dropping indexes help me to free some space ?

Comment: @Souregi It will free up some space, but I wouldn't recommend dropping indexes on such a large table, unless you really know what you're doing. If the database is used only by you and you want to free up space then yes, it could be a solution. But dropping indexes in a database used in production usually turns out to be a bad thing, if (and I repeat myself) you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Souregi If you run `exec sp_spaceused 'tablename'` then you will see the total size of the indexes on the table.

Comment: 53Go of all indexes, not too much :) (I am the only user of the table right now, My goal is to deliver a light version of the database, the non clustered indexes helped me only for the DB insert)

Answer (score 1):

Before droping any indexes run these two views.

sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats

They will let you know if any of them are being used to support queries. The last thing you want is to remove an index and start seeing full table scans on a 2TB table.

If you can't split up the table into a relational model then try these for starters.

1. Check your data types.

-Can you replace NVARCHAR with VARCHAR or NCHAR with CHAR? (they take up half the space)

-Does your table experience a lot of Updates or a lot of Inserts (above view will tell you this)? If there are very few updates then consider changing CHAR fields to VARCHAR fields. Heavy updates can cause page splits and result in poor Page fullness.

-Check that columns only storing a Date with no time are not declared as Datetime

-Check value ranges in numeric fields i.e. try and use Smallint instead of Int.

2. Look at the activity on the table, update & insert behaviour. If the activity means very few Pages are re-arranged then consider increasing your Fill Factor.
3. Look at the Plan Cache, get an idea of how the table is being queried, if the bulk of queries focus on a specific portion of the table then implement a Filtered Index.
4. Is your Clustered Index Unique? If not then SQL creates a "hidden extra Integer column" that creates uniqueness under the bonnet.

Comment: For the data types i got a varchar(22), a varbinary(max), a bit, and a date.
The Table is a static table, it will not change in the future, I'll only need clustered Index to help the user to do some fast search over it and the column is unique.

Comment: Thanks for the good information, but it did not help me with my case :)

Comment: It looks like the varbinary is the problem, if the varbinary contains a lot of duplicates then you could create a "Super Dimension" and in your table have an Integer that links to the unique value in the dimension.

Comment: the varbinary contains files, each file is different from the other

Comment: Are you on SQL Enterprise? you can use compressed tables.